# sum of squares of each digit?

Tags: c, numbers

> "the program returns 1 if the number is "happy", 0 otherwise"
> the exercise defines a happy number as the sequence that is equal to 1. conversely, the number is unhappy if the sequence is equal to 0.

EDIT: perhaps, I should've added another nested loop because I have to do the same operations for the digit of the squares of the squares of the digits. Therefore, I'm thinking about updating this code with only one for-loop.

the sequence is defined as the sum of squares of each digit.

`0` is defined by definition as an unhappy number, because it's always zero.

If a sequence like this leads to `1`, then the number is happy, if it leads to `4`, then the number is unhappy.

I've tried to do the exercise as follows:

```
int happy(unsigned int num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        return 0; 
    }
    unsigned int tmp = 0;
    unsigned int tmp_2 = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0; 
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    unsigned int sum_2 = 0; 
    while (num != 0) {
        tmp = num % 10; 
        num /= 10; 
        tmp = tmp * tmp; 
        for (unsigned int j = 0; tmp != 0; ++j) {
            tmp_2 = tmp % 10;
            sum_2 += (tmp_2 * tmp_2); 
            tmp /= 10; 
        }
    }
    if (sum_2 == 1) {
        return 1; 
    }
    if (sum_2 == 4) {
        return 0; 
    }
}
```

and this is the main():

```
int main(void) {
    int test = 0; 
    test  = happy(0); 
    test  = happy(1); 
    test  = happy(7); 
    test  = happy(8); 
    return 0; 
}
```

The program did the task correctly with `num = 0`, and with `num = 1`. but when I have `7`, debugging line by line I've seen that it doesn't do the job.
the algorithm is the following:

- it takes the least significant digit (by means of the `%` operator), and it stores the current digit in `tmp`.
- divide by 10 (by means of the `/` operator) and store the result in `num`.
- calculate the square of `tmp`.
- now the goal is to sum the digits of `tmp`, by performing the operations above but with `tmp_2` and `sum_2`.
- then, check whether or not `tmp` is equal to zero. if it's zero, do to the main loop, (the `while`loop).

Now, there's another iteration, and the program is supposed to do the same thing but with the other digit store in `num`.

When the `while` loop ends, in `sum_2` there must be only `0` or `1`, but that's not true because the `while` loop ends before that condition. What's wrong with it?

Comment: so I need an array. I think I got it

Comment: No, you do not need an array, you can test for a cycle without an array.

Answer (score 1):

Your program does not iterate on `num`, repeating the sequence `num` -> `sum of the squares of the digits`.

You should simplify the code by writing a separate function to compute the square of digits.

It is easy to prove that the sequence must repeat at some point because the sum of squares of the digits of an **n**-digit number is bound by **n***81, always smaller than 10<sup>**n**</sup> for **n** > 3. The only numbers for which `square_digits(n) > n` have at most 3 digits and a value <= 243, and extensive testing of all numbers up to 243 shows that the smallest number in all sequences is either `0`, `1` or `4`.  Any number larger than 243 produces a strictly decreasing sequence until it reaches a number in the range 1..243.

Instead of testing for 0, 1 and 4 explicitly, one can test for a cycle by comparing `num` to the smallest value seen so far in the sequence. This approach can also be used for a generalised function taking the base as an argument instead of hardcoding base `10`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned int square_digits(unsigned int num) {
    unsigned int sum = 0;
    while (num != 0) {
        unsigned int digit = num % 10;
        sum += digit * digit;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return sum;
}

int happy(unsigned int num) {
    // keep track of the smallest value
    unsigned int min = num;
    for (;;) {
        // compute the next value in the sequence
        num = square_digits(num);
        // if the smallest value occurs again, we have a cycle
        if (num == min)
            break;
    }
    // the number is happy if the smallest value is 1
    return min == 1;
}

void test(unsigned int num)  {
    printf("%u: %s\n", num, happy(num) ? "happy" : "unhappy");
}

int main() {
    for (unsigned int n = 0; n <= 100; n++)
        test(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

Comment: @4386427 yes. This operation is very famous. I wonder if the demonstration of that still remains unresolved...

Comment: It is easy to prove that the iteration must loop at some point because the sum of squares of the digits of an n-digit number is bound by n*81, always smaller than 10^n for n>3.  Instead of testing for `1` and `4` explicitly, one could test for a cycle by comparing `num` to its initial value and keep track of the smallest number encountered.

Comment: @4386427 In fact it is easy to understand why the result is always 0, 4, or 1. 0 is the case when your initial number is 0. 1 is the smallest happy number and so 4 is for the unhappies (if indeed the number is not null).

Comment: I updated the answer with a simple proof.